# Permission error when starting a microservice with Micro.mu

Tags: go, microservices, go-micro

I have just created a new microservice with `micro new <microservice_name>` using [Micro](https://micro.mu). I have then installed the needed dependencies (protobuf) and run `make proto`, as specified in the [official documentation](https://micro.mu/getting-started#creating-a-service). However, when I run `micro run .`, I get `Fork/exec /usr/local/Cellar/go: permission denied:`.

I have already tried:

- running the same command with sudo;
- checking the permissions for /usr/local/Cellar/go (drwxr-xr-x);
- checking the permissions for $HOME/bin/micro (.rwxr-xr-x);
- reinstalling Go (`brew reinstall go`).

Nothing changed: I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found a solution. The issue I was experiencing was related to Homebrew. After uninstalling Go with `brew uninstall go` and installing it with the official installer for Mac (available at the [official download page](https://golang.org/dl/)) I finally managed to start my microservice with `micro server` and `micro run .`